# "Compare to other firearm, it is...." can I use this?

Tags: word-usage

Can I use this?

Google for this is hard.
Which subject does verb "compare" point to?
Is the verb "compare" or "compared" or "compares"?

Comment: Which form is sought-after is not clear as you have not indicated what you actually want to communicate. Perhaps you mean *Compared to the other firearm, it is…* or perhaps *Compared to other firearms, it is…* or perhaps *Compare it to the other firearm: it is…* But in an instruction manual or other telegraphic English, *Compare to firearm* might be entirely legitimate.

Comment: Can you use this in what? Please provide more information to help us answer your question. (Google is not a useful teacher of English. Google is just a list of websites, and anyone can create a website.)

Answer (score 0):

Your phrase can only be

> Compare**d** to other firearms

is a shortened version of

> *(When)* compared to other firearms
>   *in comparison to other firearms*

this phrase refers to "it" in the immediately following clause in your example.

Comment: I can not edit and comment on the main question, so I want to ask here, why can't the phrase be "when compare to other firearms" in the present tense? The reason for the question is I google for the example, but it seems the only example I got is the "compared to other firearms"